# .htaccess redirect - add on a GET Variable to the end

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have some wildcard redirects which are currently working fine...

```
https://www.domain-name.com/$1
```

However, I would like to add a GET variable after it, so that in my CMS, I can trace the referrer. I have tried the below, however it just outputs the $1 to the URL.

```
https://www.domain-name.com/$1?redirect=foobar
```

Hopefully this is a simple fix!

Edit - these redirects are generated from cPanel, so the generated code is...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.domain\.uk\/\$1\?redirect\=redirect" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please post your _full_ rewriting rules, not just the target part.

Comment: hopefully, it might be a simple fix

Comment: These are client generated via cPanel, so the actual outputted code is somewhat of a nightmare...

Comment: How do you expect us to help if you do not post the relevant information? Do you expect us to _guess_ it?

Comment: I've edited my original post to put up the rules. I would of expected someone with such reputation to use the force to provide a viable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no wildcard redirect here. It just redirects the home page to literally `/$1?redirect=redirect`. Also, there's no point in escaping (`\`) any character of the target URL.

In order to redirect each request to itself with a query string appended

```
# prevent a redirect loop
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !redirect=
# append query string
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.uk/$1?redirect=foobar [R,L]
```

If you want to preserve any existing query string, add the [`QSA`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag, e.g. `R,L,QSA`

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301` ([permanent redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)). *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).